# Dynamically change object in controller using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following [simple plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HjK4OMQlbZuLqDkceuah?p=preview)

In it you can see that I am trying to bind a scope variable to a property of an object.

```
$scope.name = 'World';
var obj = {
  "name":$scope.name
}
$scope.$watch('name', function(){
  console.log(obj["name"]);
})
```

The console.log always shows World even after I change the name. How can I propagate this change to obj?

This question is to about getting the value from some other means (I.E. The function params) because I have to actually update obj for use in other code.

Comment: you are expecting inheritance from a primitive, doesn't work that way

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/fZ1LCS?p=preview

Comment: You get it PSL why don't you post it and explain a little more about the $new for the check

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `obj` directly since it is an object it can be tracked by reference:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{obj.name}}!</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="obj.name" />
</body>

$scope.obj = {
    "name": 'World'
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't help what I really need which is to auto update the obj object without having to use the watch (if possible)